# Issue with accessing duration value of an audio file stored in variable "hh"

Tags: javascript

I'm facing an issue while trying to access the duration value of an audio file that I have stored in a variable named "hh" in Foreach Loop. The audio file itself is successfully loaded into the variable, but when I attempt to retrieve the duration using hh.duration, I'm getting "NaN" instead of the expected duration value.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
function showcontent() {
    let songsarra = localStorage.getItem("Songs");
    let songa =JSON.parse(songsarra);
    
    document.getElementById("SongItemContainer").innerHTML = "";
    
    let x = 0;
    let index = 0;
    
    songa.forEach(()=>{
        let hh = new Audio(songa[x].filepath);        
        document.getElementById("SongItemContainer").innerHTML += `<div class="songItem">
        <img src="${songa[x].Coverpath}" alt="">
        <span class="songname">${songa[x].songName}</span>
        <span class="timestamp">${hh.duration} <i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can class="delete" onclick="deleteitem(${index})"></i> <i class="fa-regular  fa-circle-play current" id="${x}"></i></span>
        </div>`;
        x++;
        index++;
    });
}
```

The above code snippet results in "NaN" being printed instead of the actual duration of the audio file.

I have verified that the audio file is valid and accessible, and the loading process seems to be working correctly as I checked it in console. However, accessing the duration property returns "NaN".

Is there something I'm missing or doing incorrectly? How can I properly retrieve the duration value of the audio file stored in the variable "hh"?

Any guidance or suggestions to help resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you `console.log` the `hh` object and share the result, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hi!**

First of all, I've slightly corrected your code. You can immediately refer to the iterated song, and also get an index

Secondly, getting duration from audio is **only available when meta information becomes available**. To do this, you need to hang the handler on Audio, and after the meta information is available, you can already access the duration properties of the track

[Link to the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadedmetadata_event)

[Here is the working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-curran-xpc8v6?file=/src/index.js)

The main part:

```js
function showcontent() {
  let songsarra = localStorage.getItem("Songs");
  let songa = JSON.parse(songsarra);

  document.getElementById("SongItemContainer").innerHTML = "";

  songa.forEach((song, index) => {
    let hh = new Audio(song.filepath);

    hh.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
      document.getElementById(
        "SongItemContainer"
      ).innerHTML += `<div class="songItem">
        <img src="${song.Coverpath}" style="width: 50px;" alt="">
        <span class="songname">${song.songName}</span>
        <span class="timestamp">${hh.duration} <i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can class="delete" onclick="deleteitem(${index})"></i> <i class="fa-regular  fa-circle-play current" id="${index}"></i></span>
        </div>`;
    });
  });
}
```